# Converting Long Money String To Decimal

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I'm trying to figure out a way (or find a library) that supports long money string conversion into a decimal. I'm not sure if there's a practical way to do this with all the possible combinations.

Basically, I would need to convert something like `two hundred and thirteen dollars and fifty-two cents` into `213.52`

Does anybody know of a library that handles this already or a solution that has already been posted? I've Googled for about an hour and came up with turning dollar amounts in words.

Comment: software or library suggestion is off-topic here. Should be on [softwarerecs.se]\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try **WordToNumberConverter** NuGet

https://www.nuget.org/packages/WordToNumberConverter/

But you should be sure input matching the format.

Example of **right input** : "twenty nine **thousand** and fifty five"

while

Example of **wrong input** : "twenty nine **thousands** and fifty five"

How to use:

```
    WordToNumberConverter.WordToNumberConverter inst = 
        new WordToNumberConverter.WordToNumberConverter();

    var ddd = inst.ConvertWordToNumber("twenty nine thousand and fifty five");
```

Comment: I feel obligated to say that "nine thousand and fifty five" is not correct English. It should be "nine thousand fifty five" - the "and" is only used to indicate a transition from whole numbers to fractions (e.g. "nine thousand fifty five and four tenths")

Answer (score -1):

Humanizer should be able to help you with this and more.
You can try the following link "https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer#number-to-words".
It is quite simple to use as you can see in the example

```
1.ToWords() => "one"
10.ToWords() => "ten"
11.ToWords() => "eleven"
122.ToWords() => "one hundred and twenty-two"
3501.ToWords() => "three thousand five hundred and one"
```

Comment: I need to go the other way, not `ToWords()` rather `WordsToNumbers()` does it have this functionality?